# WSGIDaemon Process syntax error - Mod_wsgi django ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've just set up a testbed for migrating our site from managed, shared hosting to Digital Ocean.  I built the service up, because I wanted to get what was going on.  Currently, the django system works, and I can run the devserver mapped to 0.0.0.0:8000 and it serves content,but that's clearly not going to cut it for production though, and I want to make apache work. Currently working out of a virtualenv called 'env', imaginatively enough.

I've followed the [Digital Ocean quick start](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps) for this, but suspect I'm falling foul of the need to know a bit more than it provides.  Apache is there and installed, and operating correctly (at least initially) - when I access the root IP for the droplet, I get the 'It works!' message.  So, both bits work, but when I come to modify `nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and restart, I get the message that:

```
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

So it's failing at the first line of the following config(both paths are correct):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess processname python-path=/var/www/path/tosite:/var/www/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup processname
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/path/to/project/wsgi.py
```

The Traceback that I was getting originally was this:

```
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:48 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Target WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP]   File "/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:50 2014] [error] [clientIP] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Target WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP]   File "/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Target WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] mod_wsgi (pid=18936): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP]   File "/var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 02 13:47:51 2014] [error] [clientIP] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I [tried this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927345/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-apache-virtualenv-aws-wsgi), but it didn't seem to make any difference; one key thing is that I now can't *reset* the apache server as I normally would, as it won't start - so I'm uncertain if my changes are taking effect.

I also removed and reinstalled mod_wsgi to see if that was the problem, reinstalling with `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`, and tried chmod 755 the wsgi.py file.

As an aside - all of the versions of apache i've used before have had an httpd.conf file, but this doesn't seem to have one  - running ps -ef | grep apache just shows the error log and the 000-default mentioned above.

Full default-000 is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/var/www/project/projectv2:/var/www/env/lib/python2.7/site$
        WSGIProcessGroup project
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/projectv2/projectv2/wsgi.py
        ServerAdmin system@project.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Similarly, i'm not using mod_python (as per [Graeme's comment on the main question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828200/django-with-apache-and-wsgi-throws-importerror), and [I can import django.core.wsgi manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194859/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-for-uwsgi) in the shell.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the sequence of events here. Could it be that you uninstalled mod-wsgi, and then started getting the first error message you mention? Because that error implies you haven't actually activated mod-wsgi (which you can do with `sudo a2enmod wsgi`, or by manually editing /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load).

Comment: Oh dear Christ.  sudo a2enmod wsgi and it worked.  :D / :( If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it.  I can't believe I've spent a day rolling around trying to fix that and hadn't activated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you needed to enable mod-wsgi after re-installing it, by doing `sudo a2enmod wsgi`.